# Code is not working if textbox is left empty

Tags: c#, winforms

I have inserted a number textboxes in windows form which I use for my data input. In few occasions if I intentionally leave some of them empty, code doesn't work. It says "Input string was not in a correct format." Can I disable a textbox that has been linked to a variable in such a way that code doesnt break?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String FloorNumber = textBox1.Text;
        int RebarCover = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int LongitudinalRebarDiameter = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        int StirupDiameter = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        int CountOfEdgeBarsNorth = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        int CountOfEdgeBarsEast = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);                   
        textBox14.Text = RebarCover.ToString();                 

    }
```

Comment: because you cannot convert `""` or `string.Empty` to an integer.. it's staring you right in the face.. why not write some conditional checks and if it's empty or blank then default the text box to 0

Answer (score 5):

You really need to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid a fail in this situation

```
    int tempValue;
    String FloorNumber = textBox1.Text;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tempValue)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Need a valid number for RebarCover");
         return;
    }
    int RebarCover = tempValue;

    // and same code for the other textboxes that you need to convert to a Int32
    ....
```

`Int32.TryParse` tries to convert your string to an Integer and, if it fails, it return false without raising an exception. If the text could be converted the `out tempValue` variable receives the converted value and `TryParse` returns true.